# How to use HTML Agility Pack in Lightswitch 2013 Desktop Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I added the HTML Agility Pack (HAP) to my solution using Nuget. My solution uses Silverlight 5. Some functions I can call from "using HtmlAgilityPack;" but some functions I cannot call. I need to get content of URL by following code lines:

```
string Url = "http://google.com.vn"; // this line is okay
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); // this line is okay
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url); // but this line is highlighted with an error 'Error HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'Load' and no extension method 'Load' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
```

Comment: Try `LoadAsync()` and `LoadCompleted`.

Comment: LoadAsync doesnt have parameter LoadCompleted. I tried

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Extensions;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
public partial class Table1ItemsListDetail
{
    partial void Method_CanExecute(ref bool result)
    {

        // Write your code here.


    }

    partial void Method_Execute()
    {

            var wc = new HtmlWeb();
            // string url = "http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/algemeen.rss";

            wc.LoadAsync("http://google.com");

            wc.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted>(DownloadCompleted);
            //wc.
        //

    }
    void DownloadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = e.Document;
            if (doc != null)
            {
                Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(doc.DocumentNode.Element("html").InnerHtml);

                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}